# Difference between the old game.achievement / new open graph

Tags: facebook, achievements, facebook-opengraph

I'm confused about the new version of the *Open Graph* (beta). I'm currently implementing the achievements functionality into a facebook app'.

I'd like to know if there's a difference between :

- Old **game.achievements** in the og:type meta tag, and...
- New implementation of the *Open Graph* (beta) with fully customizable objects/actions

Am I supposed to use the new *Open Graph* (beta) to post my achievements instead of the old way with game.achievement ?
 
Is it two totally different things ?
Or is the **game.achievement** a predefined object type with predefined behaviors ?

Just to know what i should implement today according to the new announcements...!

Thanks in advance !

F.S.

Comment: if you are starting a new project then don't use any old/deprecated methods...

Comment: Shouldn't have used the word "old". That's the question :
Is it a new version (causing the deprecation of "game.achievement"), or are they completely different ? Didn't found anything stating that clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Achievements are just one global pre-defined action in the new Open Graph.

Use the global `game.achievement` for achievements and use custom Actions and Objects for anything that doesn't fit into an already globally defined schema.